# Playwright Python context crashes making all other contexts to crash and enter a crash loop

Tags: playwright

I have 3 browsers and up to 160 asyncio tasks. These tasks are split equally among the browsers, and I have a total of 40 browser contexts (split equally among the browsers). Sometimes, when calling 'goto', I get "Connection closed while reading from the driver" error, however, this makes all other contexts to start failing. When trying to clean up, I still get some driver errors:

```
2023-07-01 15:51:01,967 pipe closed by peer or os.write(pipe, data) raised exception.
2023-07-01 15:51:01,968 Connection closed while reading from the driver
```

---

Upon restarting the workflow, if I revisit the same URLs again, the application gets into a crash loop with the same errors. If I change the URLs, it works fine (however, revisiting the URLs later may also work fine, so it is not a particular URL that is causing this issue). I have no clue what is causing this, so I would appreciate any suggestions or at least ideas. Is this a bug from my app or Playwright? Here is the stack trace from the first occurrence of the error:

```
2023-07-01 15:50:57,535 Connection closed while reading from the driver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/uvloop_reload/reloadtraffic-python/exe.py", line 105, in worker
    await page.goto(
  File "/home/uvloop_reload/venv-uv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/async_api/_generated.py", line 9204, in goto
    await self._impl_obj.goto(
  File "/home/uvloop_reload/venv-uv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_page.py", line 495, in goto
    return await self._main_frame.goto(**locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "/home/uvloop_reload/venv-uv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_frame.py", line 147, in goto
    await self._channel.send("goto", locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "/home/uvloop_reload/venv-uv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 61, in send
    return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
  File "/home/uvloop_reload/venv-uv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 461, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
  File "/home/uvloop_reload/venv-uv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 96, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
Exception: Connection closed while reading from the driver
```

Comment: There is NO code shared to look at.

Comment: Yes, I know, however, I explained the workflow and I asked what any direcitons about what could cause this issue. I am not expecting people to find a bug in my code, more like giving me a direction to investigate further myself. I cannot post the code here, the codebase is large and it would not make sense.